# Why does C-x C-e work in foo.txt but C-M-x does not?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, eval-expression

Create a new file foo.txt and type this code in it:

```
(+ 1 2)
```

Move the cursor to the end of the line (right after the close-paren) and press `C-x C-e`. The expression is evaluated.

Move the cursor to somewhere within the expression and press `C-M-x`. There is an error message: `C-M-x is undefined`.

Now replicate the same steps in a buffer foo.el. In foo.el both `C-x C-e` and `C-M-x` work successfully.

Why does `C-x C-e` work in foo.txt but `C-M-x` not work in foo.txt?

Comment: `C-h k C-x C-e`: “... found in **global-map** ...”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of input such as `C-x C-e` is called key-binding, is defined in mode-specific keymaps. Text files are opened in `text-mode`, ELisp files are in `emacs-lisp-mode` (mode is usually selected by file extensions), so the key-binding that is not defined in each mode's keymap (defined as `-map` after the mode name) cannot be used.

Enter the `C-M-x` in a buffer foo.el after `M-x describe-key`, it shows

```
C-M-x runs the command eval-defun (found in emacs-lisp-mode-map)
...
```

saying the key binding is found(defined) in `emacs-lisp-mode-map`, not in `text-mode-map`, so if you want to use the key even for `text-mode`, this additional setting is required:

```lisp
(define-key text-mode-map (kbd "C-M-x") 'eval-defun) ;; the command name shown by `describe-key'
```

See [Major modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html) and [Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keymaps.html) in the Emacs manual.